# how to sign a digital signature on multiple Excel files?

Tags: signature, digital

I send to my boss more than 200 Excel files for signing, somehow do this promtly by VBA or another solutions can be done. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a container like [ASiC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associated_Signature_Containers) or a [XMLDsig signature with manifest](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/#sec-o-Manifest).

Comment: I found the software which help me done this task. that's pdf sign 19 euro/a year. Thanks for your sugguestion.